# Failed to obtain JDBC Connection Object does not wrap anything with requested interface when starting spring boot app

Tags: java, spring, oracle, spring-boot

I have very annoying issue and i have no idea where to start, i already checked every link on internet regarding this problem and was not able to find anything useful.

So basically i have fresh spring boot application and i am trying to connect it to existing oracle database.

My application.properties for local instance looks like this:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@ldap://oraldap1:389/DB,cn=OracleContext,dc=COMPANY,dc=com ldap://oraldap2:389/DB,cn=OracleContext,dc=COMPANY,dc=com
    username: user
    password: pass
    driverClassName: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
    hikari:
      maximum-pool-size: 30
      connection-timeout: 20000
    tomcat:
      initial-size: 2
      max-active: 20
      min-idle: 2
      max-idle: 2
  jpa:
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
        jdbc:
          use_get_generated_keys: true
```

And in my gradle.build i have this dependency:

```
compile group: 'com.oracle.database.jdbc', name: 'ojdbc8', version: '12.2.0.1'
```

When i start application i can  see 2 errors:

> 2021-08-24T17:46:03.685+02:00 WARN - 0 jvm
> org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.AbstractHealthIndicator
> {"x-company-correlation-id":"", "@trace_info":"[ebas,,,,]",
> "@message": "DataSource health check failed","@data":{}, "@exception":
> " org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Failed to
> obtain JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException:
> Object does not wrap anything with requested interface
>
> 2021-08-24T17:45:51.418+02:00 ERROR - 0 jvm
> org.hibernate.hql.spi.id.IdTableHelper
> {"x-company-correlation-id":"", "@trace_info":"[ebas,,,,]",
> "@message": "Unable obtain JDBC Connection","@data":{}, "@exception":
> " java.sql.SQLException: Object does not wrap anything with requested
> interface

And the funny thing, when i put intentionally wrong password on application startup i can see message that says:

> Unable obtain JDBC Connection","@data":{}, "@exception":
> " java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon
> denied

Of course i already know that this database url and drivers are correct because i can connect to db via dbeaver.

edit:
Here are stacktraces:

> at
> org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:82)
> at
> org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:324)
> at
> org.springframework.boot.actuate.jdbc.DataSourceHealthIndicator.getProduct(DataSourceHealthIndicator.java:122)
> at
> org.springframework.boot.actuate.jdbc.DataSourceHealthIndicator.doDataSourceHealthCheck(DataSourceHealthIndicator.java:107)
> at
> org.springframework.boot.actuate.jdbc.DataSourceHealthIndicator.doHealthCheck(DataSourceHealthIndicator.java:102)
> at
> org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.AbstractHealthIndicator.health(AbstractHealthIndicator.java:82)
> at
> org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthIndicator.getHealth(HealthIndicator.java:37)
> at
> org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpoint.getHealth(HealthEndpoint.java:81)
> at
> org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpoint.getHealth(HealthEndpoint.java:38)
> at
> org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointSupport.getContribution(HealthEndpointSupport.java:108)
> at
> org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointSupport.getAggregateHealth(HealthEndpointSupport.java:119)
> at
> org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointSupport.getContribution(HealthEndpointSupport.java:105)
> at
> org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointSupport.getHealth(HealthEndpointSupport.java:83)
> at
> org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointSupport.getHealth(HealthEndpointSupport.java:70)
> at
> org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpoint.health(HealthEndpoint.java:75)
> at
> org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpoint.health(HealthEndpoint.java:65)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
> org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:282)
> at
> org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.invoke.reflect.ReflectiveOperationInvoker.invoke(ReflectiveOperationInvoker.java:77)
> at
> org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.annotation.AbstractDiscoveredOperation.invoke(AbstractDiscoveredOperation.java:60)
> at
> org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.jmx.EndpointMBean.invoke(EndpointMBean.java:121)
> at
> org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.jmx.EndpointMBean.invoke(EndpointMBean.java:96)
> at
> com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
> at
> com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
> at
> javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1468)
> at
> javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:76)
> at
> javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1309)
> at
> javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1401)
> at
> javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:829)
> at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor99.invoke(Unknown Source)     at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
> sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:357)
> at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)    at
> sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)     at
> java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
> sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)   at
> sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:573)
> at
> sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:834)
> at
> sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:688)
> at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
> sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:687)
> at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
> at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)    Caused by:
> java.sql.SQLException: Object does not wrap anything with requested
> interface     at
> oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleConnection.isWrapperFor(OracleConnection.java:251)
> at
> com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection.isWrapperFor(ProxyConnection.java:448)
> at
> io.opentracing.contrib.spring.cloud.jdbc.JdbcAspect.getConnection(JdbcAspect.java:56)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
> org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:644)
> at
> org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:633)
> at
> org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:70)
> at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:175)
> at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:747)
> at
> org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:95)
> at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
> at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:747)
> at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:689)
> at
> com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$4d55a5a7.getConnection()
> at
> com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$eeb1ae86.invoke()
> at
> org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
> at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:769)
> at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
> at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:747)
> at
> org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:136)
> at
> org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:124)
> at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
> at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:747)
> at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:689)
> at
> com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e4736671.getConnection()
> at
> org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.fetchConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:158)
> at
> org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:116)
> at
> org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:79)
> ... 47 common frames omitted

> at
> oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleConnection.isWrapperFor(OracleConnection.java:251)
> at
> com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection.isWrapperFor(ProxyConnection.java:448)
> at
> io.opentracing.contrib.spring.cloud.jdbc.JdbcAspect.getConnection(JdbcAspect.java:56)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
> org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:644)
> at
> org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:633)
> at
> org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:70)
> at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:175)
> at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:747)
> at
> org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:95)
> at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
> at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:747)
> at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:689)
> at
> com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$4d55a5a7.getConnection()
> at
> com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$eeb1ae86.invoke()
> at
> org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
> at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:769)
> at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
> at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:747)
> at
> org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:136)
> at
> org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:124)
> at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
> at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:747)
> at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:689)
> at
> com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e4736671.getConnection()
> at
> org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122)
> at
> org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:180)
> at
> org.hibernate.hql.spi.id.IdTableHelper.executeIdTableCreationStatements(IdTableHelper.java:67)
> at
> org.hibernate.hql.spi.id.global.GlobalTemporaryTableBulkIdStrategy.finishPreparation(GlobalTemporaryTableBulkIdStrategy.java:125)
> at
> org.hibernate.hql.spi.id.global.GlobalTemporaryTableBulkIdStrategy.finishPreparation(GlobalTemporaryTableBulkIdStrategy.java:42)
> at
> org.hibernate.hql.spi.id.AbstractMultiTableBulkIdStrategyImpl.prepare(AbstractMultiTableBulkIdStrategyImpl.java:88)
> at
> org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.(SessionFactoryImpl.java:313)
> at
> org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:462)
> at
> org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1237)
> at
> org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58)
> at
> org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365)
> at
> org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:391)
> at
> org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:378)
> at
> org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1855)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1792)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:595)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
> at
> org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1108)
> at
> org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:868)
> at
> org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
> at
> org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141)
> at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747)
> at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
> at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
> at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226)
> at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215)
> at
> com.bawagpsk.msa.ebanking.ebas.Application.main(Application.java:15)

Comment: No stack trace? that could tell you if hikari or tomcat pool is causing the error. https://stackoverflow.com/a/40090148/2834978

Comment: @LMC i added stack trace, could it tell you something ?

Comment: Yes, seems to be the oracle wrapper issue. Hikari is not able to unwrap the connection: `Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Object does not wrap anything with requested interface  
 at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleConnection.isWrapperFor(OracleConnection.java:251)
 at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection.isWrapperFor(ProxyConnection.java:448)`

Comment: Fix could depend on your oracle db version

Comment: @LMC

Version is: Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0

Comment: Dialect could be `org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect` and dependency could be `implementation group: 'com.oracle.database.jdbc', name: 'ojdbc8', version: '19.11.0.0'`. Updating the driver could fix the issue, worth trying.

Comment: I already tried that unfortunately its not working

Comment: Did you updated hikari too?

Comment: @Sahbaz - just out of curiosity - why do you have both ldap and jdbc url values configured for your spring.datasource.url property in your yml file?